# Trouble with Sending an asynchronous call using HttpAsyncClient

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to send an asynchronous post request to a servlet in java. I am using apache HttpAsyncClient as shown in the following method. When I debug, I see that the process that calls this method waits until the called servlet finishes its processing. In other words, the call seems to be synchronous and not asynchronous. 
Do you know what is the part that I’m doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
public void sendPostRequestUsingHttpAsyncClient( String params)  {

    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault()) {
        client.start();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params, ContentType.create("application/json", Consts.UTF_8));
        request.setEntity(entity);
        Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(request, null);
        try {
            System.out.println(future.get().getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is blocked until successful execution of HTTP request when you do `future.get()`

It seems that your expectation of asynchrony is a bit far from what really happening in your code. To get the benefit of `HttpAsyncClient`, you can execute multiple requests in the beginning and then wait for all of them to complete using some synchronization primitive.

Comment: +1 Here is a code sample http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, future.get() was causing that wait and making the call perform as a synchronous call. I removed it and followed the example you shared. The code works correctly now.